# Adding numbers to first element of arrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose you have an arrayList of arrayLists:

```
[[a,b,6],[a,b,7],[s,d,3]]
```

I want to add a number as an index starting from 0 in first place of every `arrayList` as long as the two first elements remains the same. When it doesn't, counting must start again from 0. So I expect as a result:

```
[[0,a,b,6],[1,a,b,7],[0,s,d,3]]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried, this site is more for helping specific issues, not "I have this problem please solve it with code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate and remember the first two elements each step:

```
List<List<Object>> listOfLists = ...
Object first = listOfList.get(0).get(0);
Object second = listOfList.get(0).get(1);
int count = 0;

for (List<Object> list : listOfList) {
    Object currFirst = list.get(0);
    Object currSecond = list.get(1);
    if (!currFirst.equals(first) || currSecond.equals(second)) {
        first = currFirst;
        second = currSecond;
        count = 0;
    }
    list.add (0, count);
    ++count;
}
```